# chrome.hid.send not sending packets

Tags: google-chrome, usb, chromium, hid

I am developing a chrome app that needs to be connected to a custom HID device.I am able to receive data from the the device.
I do have write permission on hid and usb bus.Yet there is no data received by the device.
I am successfully able to send data via hidapi in a separate program.
Can you suggest any method to check whether or not chrome.hid.send is working or not?
OS : Arch Linux
Chrome version : 46.0.2490.22 beta (64-bit)

Answer (score 1):

Well the following code snippet seems to work for me : (taken from HID sample app from chrome-app-samples)

```
    function sendHid(){
        var bytes = new Uint8Array(63);
        bytes[0] = 0x01;//to send 0x01 to HID device

        chrome.hid.send(connectionId,0,bytes.buffer,function(){
        if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
            console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
            return;
           }
        else {
            console.log("Sent!");
            }
        });
       }
```